# Magento 2: Invalid block type

Tags: magento2, extensions, login

I'm getting this error in the `system.log`, When ever I access the magento login page with my module installed:

```
[2016-11-10 12:40:15] main.CRITICAL: Class Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Google\Client does not exist [] []
[2016-11-10 12:40:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login [] []
[2016-11-10 12:40:15] main.CRITICAL: Class Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Google\Client does not exist [] []
[2016-11-10 12:40:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Google\Button [] []
[2016-11-10 12:40:15] main.CRITICAL: Class Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Facebook\Client does not exist [] []
[2016-11-10 12:40:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Facebook\Button [] []
[2016-11-10 12:40:15] main.CRITICAL: Class Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Twitter\Client does not exist [] []
[2016-11-10 12:40:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Twitter\Button [] []
[2016-11-10 12:40:15] main.CRITICAL: Class Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Pixelpin\Client does not exist [] []
[2016-11-10 12:40:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Pixelpin\Button [] []
```

I tried making changes to the block reference but unable to solve the problem:

```
<referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login" name="form_additional_login" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::login.phtml">
                <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Google\Button" name="form_additional_google_button" template="inchoo/socialconnect/google/button.phtml"/>
                <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Facebook\Button" name="form_additional_facebook_button" template="inchoo/socialconnect/facebook/button.phtml"/>
                <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Twitter\Button" name="form_additional_twitter_button" template="inchoo/socialconnect/twitter/button.phtml"/>
                <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Pixelpin\Button" name="form_additional_pixelpin_button" template="inchoo/socialconnect/pixelpin/button.phtml"/>
            </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

[Module Github project](https://github.com/CallumBrankin/Magento2-Inchoo-Social-Plugin)

Comment: Is this block exist in your system ? Also, post your block file code here

Comment: @KeyurShah the block file code is too long to post so i provided a link to the module github project in the question.

Comment: Try to add module prefix in your layout: `template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::inchoo/socialconnect/google/button.phtml"`

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I gave your suggestion a go but i still get the same error